# Cut out section of a string with another string

Tags: c, string

I got this part of a C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char *mRNA = spleissen("AUAGUAAAAGCUCUGUUUAGGAGA", "GU", "AG");
    printf("mRNA: %s\n", mRNA);
    free(mRNA);
    return 0;
}
```

I have to write the function `spleissen` which should work like this: it cuts out a string which goes from a `GU` to an `AG` and everything in between those two. So the program output is:

```
mRNA: AUACUCUGAGA
```

I don't really know how I can cut those parts out.

I am not allowed to use includes other than `stdio`, `string` and `stdlib`.

Comment: and what did you try in the meantime?

Comment: Don't cut parts out ... rather make a copy of only the characters that are not between the delimiters. the function prototype should be `char *spleissen(const char *data, const char *alpha, const char *omega)` ... oh! don't forget to `free` any memory you allocate inside the function

Comment: use `strstr`, `memmove`.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *spleissen(const char *src, const char *start, const char *end){
    size_t len = strlen(src);
    char *s, *e, *ret, *work;

    ret = work = malloc(len + 1);
    strcpy(work, src);
    len = strlen(end);

    while(s = strstr(work, start)){
        if((e = strstr(s, end))==NULL)
            break;//delete upto last?
        memmove(s, e + len, strlen(e+len)+1);
        work = s;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can simply do this:

```
char *spleissen(char *array, char *G, char *A)
{
    int l=strlen(array);
    int i, j=0;
    char returnstr[10010];
    int b=0;

    for(i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
        if(G[0]==array[i] && G[1]==array[i+1])
        {
            b=1, i++;
            continue;
        }
        else if(A[0]==array[i] && A[1]==array[i+1] && b==1)
        {
            b=0, i++;
            continue;
        }

        if(b==0)
        {
            returnstr[j]=array[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return returnstr;
}
```

Comment: can't use return of local auto array variable. and note that `free(mRNA);`